# How to loop through the column names and update the data frame with the given value in the particular column

Tags: r

The role of the employee and the start date of that role is given. The data frame named "roles" contains the designation. The start date should be filled with the value given by the user for that particular designation and the remaining columns should be filled with "-"

```
roles <- data.frame(character(),character(),character(),character(), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

roles[1, ] <- ifelse(names(roles) == a,sd, "-")
roles
newrow =  data.table(`Manager_start` = roles[1,4],
                     `VP_start` = roles[1,3],
                     `AP_start` = roles[1,2],
                     `P_start` = roles[1,1])
          dbWriteTable(conn = con,"table_name",newrow,append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
```

The expected result is  the Manager column should have the value "12/12/12" and the other columns should have "-" . But random values get stored in the database say "17914"

Comment: add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `data.frame` call and then do `roles[1, ] <- ifelse(names(roles) == a,sd, "-")`

Comment: It works well.. Thanks

Comment: Use *if(roles[i] == a)* instead of  *if(roles[i] = a)* ? I can't edit it because it's less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing ahead from your attempt we can do

```
roles <- data.frame(character(),character(),character(),character(), 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

roles[1, ] <- ifelse(names(roles) == a,sd, "-")
roles

#  VP Principal AP  Manager
#1  -         -  - 12/12/12
```

---

Or another option

```
vec <- c("VP","Principal","AP","Manager")
setNames(data.frame(t(ifelse(vec == a, sd, "-"))), vec)
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated example this works

```
a <- "Manager"
sd <- "12/12/12"
roles <- data.frame(character(),character(),character(),character(), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(roles) <- c("VP","Principal","AP","Manager")

roles[1, ] <- ifelse(names(roles) == a,sd, "-")
newrow =  data.table(`Manager_start` = roles[1,4],
                     `VP_start` = roles[1,3],
                     `AP_start` = roles[1,2],
                     `P_start` = roles[1,1])

newrow
#   Manager_start VP_start AP_start P_start
#1:      12/12/12        -        -       -
```

Comment: But some junk value gets stored in the database. For Manager column the value stored in the backend is "17914"

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar That might be because the value you are assigning (`sd`) might be factor. Convert it to character using `as.character(sd)` and check the result.

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar not sure then. Would you like to update your example so that we can reproduce the issue since as of now it works on the sample data you provided ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue now? @Ronak

Comment: It is not actually clear what are you doing here? Why you are using two objects here? Why are you using `roles` as well as `new_row` ? One is data frame other is data.table.

Comment: If the role is "Manager" then the "Manager_start" should be filled with the date given and the remaining 3 columns should be filled with "-". Then these values should be appended in the table. So I use "newrow" and fill the details from the "roles" data frame. Then "newrow" is added to the table

Comment: but why do you need `newrow` at all ? since you are just copying the values from `roles` to `newrow` one by one. Instead why not append `role` directly ?

Comment: Similarly, there are many data frames that needs to be appended to the table in the backend.

Comment: I have updated the code according to the information provided and it works for me.